# How to describe symmetric nodes in a graph

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

[image: A path graph]

For instance, in the path graph $P_4$, node $1$ and $4$ are symmetric, how to mathematically  describe this in graph theory? And any algebraic properties related to this? Thanks!

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what you are asking, but one way to describe this would to say that there is an isomorphism mapping node 1 to node 4 and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks， that is what I want.

Comment: My pleasure. As ml0105 wrote below, the more precise term here is *automorphism*, i.e., an isomorphism from the graph to itself.

Answer (score 3):

I think the property you are looking for is an automorphism. An isomorphism is a homomorphism on a graph that is a bijection. It is the generally accepted notion of graph equivalence. On graphs, homomorphisms are functions that preserve adjacencies. An automorphism is an isomorphism of the graph to itself.

Are you familiar with symmetry groups? The idea of a symmetry group on a graph is to permute the vertices. A permutation that gives an isomorphism is called an automorphism. So Aut(G), the automorphism group of the graph, is a subgroup of Sym(G), the symmetry group on the graph.

Note as well this is more of an abstract algebra topic than a linear algebra topic. I noticed you tagged this with "matrices", so I just wanted to clarify.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the reason I tagged matrices is because I guess this would be related to permutation matrix, but now it seems more abstract, I will loot at it, thanks！